# Can login be implemented using polymorphism?

Tags: authentication, polymorphism, multi-user

I have different type of users such as teacher student Teacher assistant, can I implement login use polymorphism?

Every type of user has different rights and access to different functionalities of the program.

Comment: Yes, but imo it's not useful to do it that way.

Comment: @pablochan what do you mean by imo ?

Comment: Can you explain how to implement it? @pablochan

Comment: No, the question is too broad. Once you have a more specific problem, I'm sure the SO community will be happy to help.

Comment: oh and IMO means "in my opinion"

Comment: Unless there is a different mechanism for logging in depending on the user, I don't see how *polymorphism* would fit here (since every user would login by providing the username and password so the login behavior is constant)